# Why Database table did not update even I copy all files of that table from another server?

Tags: mysql, linux, database, server

I have wrong data in one table niftynext50_ns_1min, which is in database prochart_india_1min.
So I copy right data for this table from another server using rsync command of linux,

```
sudo rsync -IavPe ssh 192.168.0.102:/var/lib/mysql/prochart_india_1min/niftynext50_ns_1min* /var/lib/mysql/prochart_india_1min/
```

it give output:

```
receiving incremental file list
niftynext50_ns_1min.MYD
      361398 100%  344.66MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#1, to-check=2/3)
niftynext50_ns_1min.MYI
       92160 100%   43.95MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#2, to-check=1/3)
niftynext50_ns_1min.frm
        8902 100%    4.24MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#3, to-check=0/3)

sent 4016 bytes  received 9093 bytes  26218.00 bytes/sec
total size is 462460  speedup is 35.28
```

and i check file size after transfer data,file at both server are same....
So data files tranfer successfully but when I check data in table niftynext50_ns_1min, its data not updated, it shows old data.

so what should I do for update my table...

Comment: Did you replace database files while MySQL server was running?

Comment: yes, my database was running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by simple SQL Query Issue is solved:
Flush Tables;

this query delete cache memory so tables show updated data.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to copy database files to another database server, the safest way is:

1. Stop mysqld daemon
2. Replace database files
3. Start mysqld

Replacing database files while server is running is asking for trouble. In best case, you get old data. In worst case, you corrupt your data.